# Como efetiva mensagem de sucesso no Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Estou precisando implementar uma mensagem de sucesso que seja mostrado via json, por quando minha mensagem está retornando dessa forma abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não sei como implementar essa mensagem, eu tentei dessa forma;

```
@PostMapping
public  ResponseEntity<Employee> criar(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee, BindingResult result,  HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("mensagem", "Cadastro de Employee feita com sucesso");

    Employee employeeSalva = employeeRepository.save(employee);
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().path("/{codigo}")
            .buildAndExpand(employeeSalva.getId()).toUri();
        response.setHeader("Location", uri.toASCIIString());

        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(employeeSalva);


}
```

Eu tentei usar o método **addAttribute**, porém não tive sucesso, por favor ,alguém poderia me ajudar no código para eu conseguir implementar uma mensagem de sucesso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa retornar um objeto que represente os campos que quer retornar, no caso apenas uma mensagem de sucesso.

Portanto, você precisa criar uma espécie de Dto, preencher ele com a mensagem e retornar no ResponseEntity:

```
public class MensagemSucessoDto {
    private String mensagem;
    //criar construtor, get e set
}
```

Ficando mais ou menos assim seu código:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto> criar(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee, BindingResult result,  HttpServletResponse response) {

    Employee employeeSalva = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().path("/{codigo}")
            .buildAndExpand(employeeSalva.getId()).toUri();
        response.setHeader("Location", uri.toASCIIString());

        MensagemSucessoDto mensagemSucessoDto = new mensagemSucessoDto("Cadastro de Employee feita com sucesso");
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(mensagemSucessoDto);
}
```

Contudo, não seria a forma mais Rest de se fazer isto. É comum, ao criar um recurso via POST, você retornar os valores do recurso criado (Employee) e dizer se foi sucesso ou não via o código HTTP, que seria o `201 CREATED`. O código, seguindo este padrão, seria assim:

1. Retornar um Dto que represente os campos que quer retornar: `id`, `name`, `salary`.
2. Salva o recurso Employee.
3. Você cria este Dto (`EmployeeDto`), preenche o Dto com os dados de Employee e retorna ele no `ResponseEntity`, usando o método que usou (`ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(employeeDto)`) ou `new ResponseEntity<>(employeeDto, HttpStatus.CREATED)`.

No mais, não recomendo ficar usando a mesma classe `Employee` no Request e Response, ainda mais se ela for uma entidade do hibernate (como desconfio que seja, no seu caso).